# Improving Von Neumann's Unfair Coin Solution

Tags: probability, puzzle, recreational-mathematics

> If a cheat has altered a coin to prefer one side over another (a
>   biased coin), the coin can still be used for fair results by changing
>   the game slightly. John von Neumann gave the following
>   procedure:
>
> Toss the coin twice. If the results match, start over, forgetting both
>   results. If the results differ, use the first result, forgetting the
>   second.

Are there ways of doing this (can we tweak this procedure) to reduce the number of expected flips needed (for a realization of heads or tails)?

Comment: What is the expectation for von Neumann's method?  Clearly it depends on the bias, and it's infinite of the coin always lands heads.

Comment: Depends. Do you know how biased the biased coin is?

Comment: Somewhat tangentially, the big problem with Neumann-style debiasers is that they assume the coin tosses to be independent. In the real world, biased randomness sources are often also autocorrelated, and it's possible for a Neumann debiaser to actually make such a source *more* biased.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it depends on knowing the exact bias of the coin. For a simple example, if you know the coin comes up heads exactly one-third of the time (in the long run), then you can flip the coin twice, call it heads if you get heads once, tails if you get tails twice, do-over if you get heads twice. You get a decision 8 times out of 9, leading to a lower number of expected flips than for the von Neumann solution.

EDIT: There's a very nice discussion of the problem, especially the case where you don't know the bias of the coin, at http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf [link updated 19/07/12]

MORE EDIT: There's a fair bit of literature on this problem. Here's a sampling of what's out there:

MR0723740 (85f:60020) 
Stout, Quentin F.; Warren, Bette; 
Tree algorithms for unbiased coin tossing with a biased coin, 
Ann. Probab. 12 (1984), no. 1, 212–222.

MR1763468 (2001f:65009) 
Juels, Ari; Jakobsson, Markus; Shriver, Elizabeth; Hillyer, Bruce K.; 
How to turn loaded dice into fair coins, 
IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 46 (2000), no. 3, 911–921. 
65C10 (94A60)

MR1763481 (2001a:65006) 
Ryabko, Boris Ya.; Matchikina, Elena;
Fast and efficient construction of an unbiased random sequence, 
IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 46 (2000), no. 3, 1090–1093. 
65C10 (65C05)

MR1763482 (2001d:68177) 
Näslund, Mats; Russell, Alexander; 
Extraction of optimally unbiased bits from a biased source,  IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 46 (2000), no. 3, 1093–1103. 
68Q99

MR2245123 (2007d:94019) 
Cicalese, Ferdinando; Gargano, Luisa; Vaccaro, Ugo;
A note on approximation of uniform distributions from variable-to-fixed length codes,
IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 52 (2006), no. 8, 3772–3777. 
94A29 (94A45)

MR2300366 (2008b:65010) 
Pae, Sung-il; Loui, Michael C.;
Randomizing functions: simulation of a discrete probability distribution using a source of unknown distribution, 
IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 52 (2006), no. 11, 4965–4976. 
65C10 (68W20)

Comment: The *nice discussion* you mention is indeed accessible and it provides the relevant references, among which the paper *Iterating von Neumann’s Procedure* by Yuval Peres in The Annals of Statistics.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning here that the theoretical best we can do (a lower bound on the number of flips needed), which the best solutions get closer to, is $1/H(p,q)$ flips to get each decision on average, where $p$ is the probability of heads, $q = 1-p$ is that of tails, and the entropy function $H(p,q)=p\lg\frac1p+q\lg\frac1q$ (here $\lg$ is logarithm to base $2$). For an unbiased coin, $p=q=1/2$, so $H(1/2,1/2) = 1/2\lg2+1/2\lg2=1$, which is consistent. For $p=1/3,q=2/3$, the lower bound is about $1.089$ flips per bit, and the solution in the first para achieves $9/8=1.125$ flips per bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If the coin has a bias $0<p<1$ then the information you get from tossing the coin is

$$
\operatorname{E}(p):=-p\log_2(p) - (1-p)\log_2(1-p).
$$

For each coin toss as input you receive $\operatorname{E}(p)$ entropy but only return on average $p(1-p)$ entropy in the output so you must be losing something.