# Is it possible to flip an unbalanced coin in a balanced manner?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say, I have a coin and the up-face is two times heavy than the down-face. If I flip the coin as usual, the probability of face-down is two times of that of face-up. Now, if I make the following agreement: only if two successive face-down occurs, I output "face-down"; otherwise, I always output "face-up". By doing so, is the output sequence balanced?

More in general, say I have a sampling algorithm that output i from the space S with probaibility p(i). Now, if I want a new sampling algorithm that sample i from S ***in a random and uniform manner***, i.e., selecting i from S with exact probability 1/|S|, how can I do?

Comment: Are you willing to specify a tolerance $\epsilon$ and accept a solution where the probability of selecting $i$ is within $\epsilon$ of $1/|S|$?

Comment: It is ok! But I want to tolerance is negligible.

Comment: is $p(i)$ unknown to you or do you know it?  Momo's answer below deals with the case where $p(i)$ is unknown and you want to produce 0-1 outputs that have probability 1/2.

Comment: See also this question, which deals with a different problem in which the random inputs 0 or 1 with probability 1/2, but the output has $|S|=3$.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways

Comment: In my question, p(i) is known.

Comment: The question that I linked to shows how this can be done exactly with an acceptance/rejection method.  If you want to use a fixed number of random inputs, then you can approximate the desired output, but it may not be possible to get it exactly.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146605/improving-von-neumanns-unfair-coin-solution

Answer (score 3):

The way you do for the coin is that you flip twice, and reject the flips if outputs are identical ($HH$ or $TT$). When you get two different outputs ($HT$ or $TH
$), then you output for example: $h$ if you have $HT$ and $t$ if you have $TH$. It is easy to see that the probability for outputting $h$ and $t$ are both equal to $1/2$

To generalize this, you have to use some information theory (calculate the bits of entropy of your biased die, generate a mapping and calculate its efficiency). You may take a look at [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177692552) if you want the details.

Comment: It is a great suggestion! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a clever bit of von Neumannery, as so many things are.

Comment: According to the paper suggested by Momo, p(i) is unknown but constant  for all n. What if p(i) is known but variable according to different i?